# S3 policy to stop hotlinking?

Tags: json, amazon-s3

Our current S3 policy reads as:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "45103629-690a-4a93-97f8-1abe2f9bb68c",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::incredibad29/*"
    }
]
}
```

This just allows anyone to access files from within.

We want to add a hotlinking statement, so users can ONLY acccess the file if referred from our site. So from a domain starting with incredibad29.com or www.incredibad.com

I just can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is for images and other *media* types, there is a known hack that uses content type headers:

> [There’s a workaround that you may use to block hotlinking of selective images and files that you think are putting a major strain in your Amazon S3 budget.
>   When you upload a file to your Amazon S3 account, the service assigns a certain Content-Type to every file based on its extension. For instance, a .jpg file will have the Content-Type set as image/jpg while a .html file will have the Content-Type as text/html. A hidden feature in Amazon S3 is that you can manually assign any Content-Type to any file, irrespective of the file’s extension, and this is what you can use to prevent hotlinking.](http://www.labnol.org/internet/prevent-image-hotlinking-in-amazon-s3/13156/)

From: http://www.labnol.org/internet/prevent-image-hotlinking-in-amazon-s3/13156/

---

I think this is pretty much the basic technique. However, if you skim the 6350 results for `[google s3 hotlinking deny](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=s3+hotlinking+deny&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) you might find alternative ways :)

Comment: It's not so much we're worried about the hotlinking perse, we just want the files to only be accessible when referred from our website.

Comment: I guess you could proxy the request via your own webserver; check the referrer header on your webserver and only passthrough to S3 using Query String Authentication using a suitably small expiration time